# How to find a general reason for a Segmentation Fault for a binary file, without the source code?

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault

Our team has a binary executable for which we don't have the source code. The only thing we know is that it was most probably written in Fortran, and that it was complied by a GCC 6.3.0 toolchain. It is a scientific code that reads some binary files (sizes ranging from megabytes to gigabytes, produced by another similar executable), does some heavy calculations, and puts the results into another file (on the order of 100Mb).

The issue is that for certain simulation cases, it runs without issue; and for others, it crashes with a segmentation fault without any output. Our team has spent the past month trying different input parameters and different systems, and failed to find the cause. We also don't have any support for this code, as the original developers left academy. We tried to contact them without success.

In general, is it possible to find at least a general idea about the reason of a segmentation fault that would help us , such as:

1. Attempting to read a too big file;
2. Some internal variable, like an array, growing too big in size
3. Incompatibility with a certain shared library present on the system
4. Issue with the compiler itself, or a system instruction,
5. Incompatible processor/memory architecture (e.g. x86 VS amd64, Intel/AMD processor, ...)
6. or something else?

Knowing this, and the theoretical background of the calculations it does, would at least help us find a general direction.

**How does such a process, debugging of a segmentation-faulting binary black box, look like?** Is there any online resource I could refer to? I attempted to find such information, but I failed to find anything. I'm fairly experienced with high-level languages (such as Python/bash), and have a general fluency in C (in the sense that I can write codes that get stuff done, but nothing hacky-fancy), but nothing deeper, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

If the solution is system-specific, this code is executed in a Linux environment, on an x86/64 architecture.

Comment: I guess depending on the system, but the crash should produce something like a mem/core dump pointing to the place in the code that's causing the crash. That's the starting point. From there there's binary analysis of the code, that might lead to the understanding of the situation for this crash.

Comment: @francescalus may I ask why was the Fortran tag removed? I don't want to undo your edit as it is probably well be founded, just it seems relevant to me as the (missing) source code was Fortran, and it went through a fortran compiler.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik The system is a GNU Linux server, x86/64 architecture, for which we don't have superuser access. Where should I look for such a dump? How is such a binary analysisis done? If someone could point me to a resource to figure this out, that would already be a great answer.

Comment: If your segfaulting black box was written in C or C++ instead, would your question or debugging approach be any different?

Comment: @Neinstein if you don't have superuser access it might be required to ask such person for configuring that the dump is created when seg fault occurs. As for the process for finding out the cause I'm not sure if there's any particular resource. You open up the binary in RE tool and try to understand the flow that causes the crash. So general RE practices applies. It's really case specific I think so not sure if you can get step-by-step instructions.

Comment: @francescalus I honestly don't know. I assume it's possible there are different tools for these languages, since they are pretty different.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I see, the SU rights are ultimately solvable so that's fine. But in this case, what you say is there's no such tool that could help me get even a very vague, high-level idea about the issue, such as whether it is an environment VS data error; and that the process in general is involved and requires specialized expertise, right? That's unfortunate.

Comment: @Neinstein I think such tool is any tool that can read core dump (`gdb`) but that's not an automatic process. For example if the crash is next to a call that allocates a memory it could be a hint that program can't allocate what it needs